# Checking if Microsoft Security Essentials is Installed on Machine

Tags: c#, windows, registry, antivirus

So I have this installer script that I wrote that automatically installs several different products on the target machine. At one point I'm checking to see if the machine (Windows 7) has **Microsoft Security Essentials** installed - if it doesn't then I install the program. This code below is written in C#, but the problem may be applicable to other languages as well.

Some facts to assist those with answering:

- MSE is 64-bit on 64-bit machines and 32-bit on 32-bit machines (there are two different installers) Hence, the the path in the registry is always: **SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**.
- The process that is automating the install is run as administrator. I'm able to see the keys of other programs in the same directory.

My view in the Registry Editor:

[image]

My Method:

```
private static bool DoesMseExist()
{
    string location = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(location))
    {
         foreach (string subKey in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
         {
              using (RegistryKey productKey = rk.OpenSubKey(subKey))
              {
                  if (productKey != null)
                  {                     
                      if (Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
                                       .Contains("Microsoft Security Client"))
                      {
                         return true;
                      }
                  }
              }
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

This never finds the key. Any assistance in discovering why would be much appreciated.

For the time being I am using the following as a substitute.

```
string MseLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\msseces.exe";
return (File.Exists(MseLocation));
```

Comment: Did you compile your app for x86 platform?

Comment: Shouldn't `string location` use `@` as well?

Comment: It does. The actual code uses a constant. I'll fix it.

Comment: @DerekW check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx if you compile for x86 and run on a 64bit OS you can't read that key

Comment: Very Interesting. Thank you for this... I'm working on a workaround. Seems Microsoft provides one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using .NET 4.0 which provides a very clean solution for accessing the 64 bit registry from a 32 bit process. Otherwise, if you're using an earlier version of the Framework then you need to use P/Invoke and call the function `RegOpenKeyEx` with the **KEY_WOW64_64KEY** flag from the `WINAPI` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But onto the solution that I used.

```
private static bool DoesMseExist()
{
       using (RegistryKey localMachineX64View = 
                    RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
                    RegistryView.Registry64))
       {
           using (RegistryKey rk = localMachineX64View.OpenSubKey(location))
           {
               foreach (string subKey in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
               {
                   using (RegistryKey productKey = rk.OpenSubKey(subKey))
                   {
                       if (productKey != null)
                       {
                           if (Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
                              .Contains("Microsoft Security Client"))
                           {
                               return true;
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
      }
      return false;
}
```

I was writing a P/Invoke solution to this problem, but then I came across [this](http://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/accessing-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-process/). All you need to do is use `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)` and you will overcome the registry redirection. It's a very easy to understand and readable approach compared to the P/Invoke solution, in my opinion.